# How can I add subdomains to letsencrypt using certbots?

Tags: postfix, ssl, dovecot, letsencrypt, certbot

I have certbot installed and successfully use it to encrypt my homepage.

Now i tried to setup an email system for my website using dovecot and postfix.

I got it mostly running, only problem is, that thunderbird gives me a warning about the adress being fraudulent because I use the ssl key of mysite.com for imap.mysite.com (same for smtp)
So how can I add imap.mysite.com and smtp.mysite.com to the existing mysite.com certificate using certbot in order to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use the `--expand` option of certbot

`--expand` tells Certbot to update an existing certificate with a new certificate that contains all of the old domains and one or more additional new domains. With the `--expand` option, use the `-d` option to specify all existing domains and one or more new domains.

Example :

```
certbot --expand -d mysite.com,imap.mysite.com,smtp.mysite.com
```

https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#re-creating-and-updating-existing-certificates

Comment: thanks, ill check this off once I got it working